# Reduce the time taken by Java program

Tags: java, runtime

I'm reading thousands of records and fetch some particular fields and do some validations(like ==0 or ==1) and then need to do some manipulations like, if some field x in each record is < 10, set field y = some value.. like that.

So about 50 some manipulations i'm doing. I'm using Stringbuilder so as to extract particular field and compare them with some values and replace with some values.

I have splitted the manipulations into 2 sets and running them concurrently with blocking queues. So that, once first record finsihes set1, then given to set2. simultanously another record can use set1.

But, the whole process takes a lot of time like if use some 100 records, it requires about 100 seconds. I tried with a input of some 10k records and took almost 3 hours.

Is there a way to reduce the time? i surely need to reduce the time taken.

Comment: Have you worked out where the time is going at the moment? Try using a profiler to work out what's happening. If that doesn't help, *show us the code*. We can't guess where the bottleneck without seeing your code. In particular, you talk about "using StringBuilder so as to extract particular field" but that really doesn't tell us much. It sounds like you've got a reasonably linear "time per record" of about 1 second though, so it seems likely that the problem is in the per-record handling rather than something to do with the number of records.

Comment: Yes. To apply all the manipulations (set 1 and set 2), it takes almost 1 second for 1 record. I wish to reduce the time taken.

Comment: Right. So you need to find out why it's taking that time. Do you understand that without seeing any code, we can't really give any advice beyond "use a profiler"?